# Prevent IntelliJ from asking to add files to git if they're already declared in .gitignore

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gitignore

When IntelliJ detects a file in the project that isn't in git, it will ask if I want to add the file(s).  This is normally fine, but it's asking even if that file matches an entry in .gitignore.  I know it matches, and that IJ knows it matches, because the commit dialog won't show that file.  Is there a way to make it stop asking about adding these files, but continue asking for other files?  The only thing I can think of that's unusual is I open IJ at a subfolder rather than the root of the git project.  That doesn't seem like it should be significant.

```
 % git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
```

.gitignore contains

```
**/dbUpdate.log
**/dbRollback.log
**/DBSchemaContent.lst
```

and IJ will ask about adding files when these files get created.

Comment: Are the files that IJ asks to add *already in git*? Then that behavior is correct. `.gitignore` doesn't matter when files are *already commited and you change them*. This is the case for 90% of all "my .gitignore is ignored"-type questions. If that's not it, then please [edit] your question to include the output of `git status` and the content of your `.gitignore` (at least the relevant parts).

Comment: @JoachimSauer I was thinking the same thing, but this phrase from the question: "because the commit dialog won't show that file" implies it is not already tracked...

Comment: Do you have multiple repositories/submodules in your project? 
What do you see under File | Settings | Version Control | Directory Mappings? Is there a parent directory (for your project) is listed?

Comment: @JoachimSauer No, they aren't tracked.

Comment: @RuslanKuleshov Just one repo, no submodules, just the project root directory in directory mappings.